# How to fix angular 2 error Cannot read property 'getOptional'?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am getting my head around angular 2 and trying to define a service called searchservice and inject this in the bootstap part:

```
import {SearchService} from 'src/service';
```

This is what the service looks like:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {URLSearchParams, Jsonp} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  search (name: string) {
        http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q='+name.value+'&type=artist')
        .map(response=>response.json());
  }
}
```

However how can I fix this error that comes up when running the app?:

```
VM337 angular2-polyfills.js:138 Error: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined
    Error loading http://run.plnkr.co/fGkpQYXMc0eGUy6e/src/boot.ts
    at _runAppInitializers (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js:14832:25)
    at PlatformRef_._initApp (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js:14813:7)
    at PlatformRef_.application (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js:14768:22)
    at Object.bootstrap (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js:25054:64)
    at execute (http://run.plnkr.co/fGkpQYXMc0eGUy6e/src/boot.ts!transpiled:60:23)
    at u (https://rawgit.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js:5:97)
    at Object.execute (https://rawgit.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js:5:3188)
    at y (https://rawgit.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js:4:9948)
    at w (https://rawgit.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js:4:10327)

plunkr ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/F6TSGfyRnR5jvbpiv2QJ?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part of the error is the line above the one you listed, which says:

> Cannot resolve all parameters for SearchService(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

Your search service is trying to define a variable of type `Http` but you didn't import `Http` into the service.

change the import line to `import {URLSearchParams, Jsonp, Http} from 'angular2/http';`.